# how to export MBeans data/statistics from JVisualVM

Tags: java, jvisualvm, mbeans

When I do a JMX connect to a java application using **JVisualVM** with **MBeans** plugin installed, I could see different MBeans configured in the application. However in order to analyze an issue. I need to export this data, from a production system, to a file/report and be able to open this later.

> Is there a way to download the MBeans statistics.

Comment: Did you find a GUI to export MBeans? So far it seems you have to write a small jva application to extract the available JMX data